# How can I download "Afinn" and "NRC" lexicon in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, tidytext

I'm trying to `get_sentiments("afinn")` and the "nrc" but I get this message:

> Error: The textdata package is required to download the NRC word-emotion association lexicon. 
>       Install the textdata package to access this dataset.

How can I install the textdata package?

Comment: Hi @Philip! In R, you can install packages with the function `install.packages()`. When you want to install different packages, just include the name of the package within the parenthesis. In your example, this would install `textdata`: `install.packages("textdata")`.

Comment: If you want some context on why this is happening, the following post by Julia Silge (co-author of tidytext) could be useful. 

https://juliasilge.com/blog/sentiment-lexicons/

I'm guessing you might have just updated tidy text and are confused why previously working functions now require you to have additional libraries installed ... 

The solution is what cimentadaj suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can install R packages via the `install.package("textdata")` function. Instead of "textdata" you can write each package that you need, but make sure that after installing a package use `library("textdata")` function before calling its functions..